# Problem of adding to hook with expansion

Tags: macros, pdftex, expansion

I have a command `\mthook` and i want to define a new command `\apptomt` that allows me to appand to `\mthook` (without use of `\write`).

Some thing like

```
\newcommand{\apptomt}[1]{\g@addto@macro\mthook{\gdef \csname  mt#1\endcsname {foo}}}
```

so that **mtfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mthook}{}
\newcommand{\apptomt}[1]{....}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\mthook}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\mt{section}
\apptomt{\mt}
\def\mt{subsection}
\apptomt{\mt}
\end{document}
```

gives **mtfile.aux**

```
\relax 
\gdef\mtsection{foo}
\gdef\mtsubsection{foo}
```

Comment: `etoolbox` provides `\appto\mthook{whatever}`.

Comment: @Manuel thanks i am not  sure how it can help,  if you have a complete answer please add it.

Comment: do you need to do anything with the hook other than write it out? (if so can add `\string` versions of the commands that are safe to write, if not need to alter the write to make things safe at that time

Comment: all i need is write it :-)

Comment: It's completely unclear what writing (the expansion of) `\mthook` to the aux file should do.

Comment: @touhami why have the hook macro at all rather than simply writing to the aux file?

Comment: @egreg sorry,  in others words what  can replace `...` in **mtfile.tex** to get **mtfile.aux**

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i need write in the end.

Comment: @touhami why? seems very odd, to be honest. If you are just writing `\gdef` then why does it matter where they are in the aux file?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not sure I understand,  but `\gdef...{foo}` and foo can be last page number or last section heading so i am not sure but this is the way usuelly.

Comment: perhaps your example doesn't show enough of your real intention `foo` as written is a constant (and you can't easily get the last page number from an `\immediate\write` in `\AtEndDocument`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mthook}{}
\newcommand{\apptomt}[1]{%
  \xdef\mthook{%
    \mthook^^J\string\gdef\expandafter\string\csname mt#1\endcsname{foo}}}
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\mthook}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\mt{section}
\apptomt{\mt}
\def\mt{subsection}
\apptomt{\mt}
\end{document}
```

Produces an aux file:

```
\relax 

\gdef\mtsection{foo}
\gdef\mtsubsection{foo}
```